# Sets cardinality definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about cardinality definition. How can we formally define cardinality for finite set using only maps from natural numbers to the set?

**UPD**

One says that the cardinality can be defined using subset of set of natural numbers, but I have limitation - I can't simply choose some subset, so we
also need to use in the definition maps that select elements of the set with some properties.

Answer (score 2):

The set $A$ is finite and has cardinality $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if there is a bijection from the set $\displaystyle \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ to $A$ for some natural number $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of $A$ is equal to $n$ where $n$ is the smallest natural number for which there exists a surjective function $f:\mathbb N\to A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ if and only if $a\equiv b\mod n.$